# ES6/React: Why is my triple-nested setState update not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread-syntax

I have a state object with three nest properties that I need to update only value at a time. So I use ES6 spread syntax to update the state, but for some reason it's given me undefined property type error whenever I run it.

When I only had two nested properties, it worked fine. What is the issue?

```
method(type, row, col) {
        this.setState({
            changedCells: {
                ...this.state.changedCells,
                [type]: {
                    ...this.state.changedCells[type],
                    [row]: {
                        ...this.state.changedCells[type][row],
                        [col]: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When the changedCells state is initially empty. And the setState method is like this, denoted with the asterisks, it runs fine. But in my first example with the cellState empty, and the type='wood', row=0, col=0, it does not work but works in the second example.

```
method(type, row, col) {
        this.setState({
            changedCells: {
                ...this.state.changedCells,
                [type]: {
                    ...this.state.changedCells[type],
                    [row]: {
                        ...this.state.changedCells[row], ***CHANGED***
                        [col]: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the initial value of your state?

Comment: Is `this.state.changedCells[type]` guaranteed to exist? If not `this.state.changedCells[type][row]` is always going to throw, regardless of merging logic.

Comment: @AlexYoung The initial state is changedCells is empty.

Comment: @loganfsmyth It should be guaranteed to exist. Hmm I had no trouble with the code before when I only did one associative [index], had by accident ...this.state.changedCells[row] instead of ...this.state.changedCells[type][row]. So I guess that's causing the issue. Why is that and what do you suggest as a fix?

Comment: To give you a real answer here, we need an actual functional example that is runnable. The `setState` and such here don't matter. Remove them and show an example of what `changedCells` would be with examples of `type` and `row` and `col` that cause the error.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Added example in post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your initial state is:

```
this.state = {
    changedCells: {}
};
```

Then your property accessing evaluates as follows:

`this.state.changedCells` evaluates to {}

`this.state.changedCells[type]` evaluates to undefined

`this.state.changedCells[type][row]` TypeError: Cannot read property row of undefined

Your code worked previously because you can use the spread operator on undefined:

```
{...undefined} === {}
```

You can solve your problem in two ways.  Either initialise the state to contain every `type` and `row` it needs, e.g.

```
this.state = {
    changedCells: {
        typeA: {
            row1: {
                col1: false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and so on.  This is fine if you have a well defined set of types, rows and columns, but impractical if you have a lot of them or don't know their names up front.

The other option is to provide a default empty object when the object might be undefined:

```
method(type, row, col) {
    this.setState({
        changedCells: {
            ...this.state.changedCells,
            [type]: {
                ...this.state.changedCells[type],
                [row]: {
                    ...(this.state.changedCells[type] || {})[row],
                    [col]: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are some tools out there to make your life easier.  You could use lodash `get` to retrieve the property, providing a default value.

```
method(type, row, col) {
    this.setState({
        changedCells: {
            ...(_.get(this.state, "changedCells", {})),
            [type]: {
                ...(_.get(this.state, ["changedCells", type], {})),
                [row]: {
                    ...(_.get(this.state, ["changedCells", type, row], {})),
                    [col]: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second option (default empty object) worked great! Thanks for the detailed explanation. It helped me understand my issue and taught me me some new things. I'll install that immutability-helper!

Comment: I deleted that part of the answer because it wouldn't actually work in your situation. Oops. Nonetheless it is a very helpful library!

Comment: Yeah just tried it, doesn't work. Still, thanks for great step-by-step explanation and answer.